# Hello!!!. So in a quiz que were given the following classes and we were asked to give the output.

Tags: polymorphism

//  I GOT THE WRONG ANSWER, BUT EVERY TIME I TRACED AGAIN I GET THE SAME ANSWER. I DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHY IT PRINTS SETTING FOUR TIMES.

```
public class A{ 
           public int number; 
           public A(){ 
             setNumber(0); 
           } 
           public void setNumber(int d){
             number = d;
           }
           public String toString(){ 
             return number+":I am A";
           }
        }



        public class B extends A{
         public B(){ 
             super(); 
         } 
         public void setNumber(int d){ 
             System.out.println("Setting"); 
             number = d; 
         } 
         public String toString(){
           return super.toString()+" - I am B"; 
         }
        }


        //AND THIS IS THE MAIN METHOD

        public class C{
            public static void main(String[] args){
                A one = new A();
                B two = new B(); //no empty constructor
                A three = new B();
                three.setNumber(5);
                two.setNumber(3);
                one.setNumber(1);
                System.out.println(three);
                System.out.println(two);
                System.out.println(one);
            }

      //  THIS IS MY ANSWER:
        Setting
        Setting
        5:I am A - I am B
        3:I am A - I am B
        1:I am A
```

AND THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER:I DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHY IT PRINTS SETTING MORE THAN TWO TIMES
            Setting
            Setting
            Setting
            Setting
            5:I am A
            3:I am A - I am B
            1:I am A

```
      //  THANKS GUYS FOR YOUR HELP!!!!
```

Comment: Please don't shout. It will take some time to clean up.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what Stack Overflow is - we are not a site where we will do your work for you. You need to make an effort first - show us this effort and explain exactly where you are stuck. We can help with that.

Comment: sorry for not being clear but I do not think you understood my question. This is not a Homework. This was a question from a test that I took weeks ago.  It seems like you did not read till the endThanks for your time anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two additional `setting` are printed by `B`'s constructor. `B`'s constructor calls `A`'s constructor which then calls `B`'s **overridden** `SetNumber` Function which prints `setting`. `B`'s constructor is called twice and SetNumber is called directly twice leading to four `Settings`.